# How can we find length of v in inner space product using basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider R³ as inner product space with standard inner product. Let W be the subspace of R³ with basis B = {(1,0,−2),(−3,2,1)} and let
v = (−1,2,−3) be in W.
(i) Find the length of v directly.
(ii) Using the Gram-Schmidt process, transform B into an orthonormal basis B' for W.
(iii) Find the length of v by using the coordinate vector of v with respect to B'.

Comment: To be clear, you can do parts (i) and (ii), but you want to know how to do (iii)?

Comment: No, I want to know all the part....

Comment: Part (i) is just applying the formula for the norm. Do you know this formula?

Comment: No... Sir, Actually I m not able to solve this problem.

Comment: Well, the norm with standard inner product on $\Bbb{R}^3$ is given by$$\|(x, y, z)\| = \sqrt{(x, y, z) \cdot (x, y, z)} = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}.$$I'm worried that if you're not familiar with this, you might be too far for us to help you with this question.

Comment: Sir, I did first and second part but i am not sure for the solution so just needed the answer.

Comment: And sir I m familiar with the part ...which you explained in your earlier comment..☺️

Comment: Good! For the third one, you can use Pythagoras's theorem. If you have an orthonormal basis $b_1, b_2$, and a vector $v$ in the span of these vectors, then you can write $v = (v \cdot b_1) b_1 + (v \cdot b_2) b_2$. Using Pythagoras's theorem, since the summands are orthogonal, we have $\|v\|^2 = (v \cdot b_1)^2 + (v \cdot b_2)^2$.

Comment: Thank you sir for the hint ...sir please can you help in the second part also ....I m not sure of my answer.

Comment: Sir, I solved part (I) and (II) ...but still I am not able to solve the thirt part ....please send me the solution.

Comment: What did you get as an answer for (ii)?

Comment: I have done all the parts .....thanks for your efforts ☺️